# Não consigo fechar o modal aberto

Tags: javascript

```
const fechar = document.querySelector(".fechar")
createCardsCandidatos(dados);

function createCardsCandidatos(listaCandidatos) {
  listaCandidatos.forEach((candidato) => {
    const candidatoEl = document.createElement("div");
    candidatoEl.classList.add("item");
    candidatoEl.innerHTML = `
        <img class="box-filme" src="${candidato.caminhoImg}">
         `;
    const candidatoModal= document.createElement("div")
    candidatoModal.classList.add("container-modal")
    candidatoModal.innerHTML=`
    <div class="modal" id="iniciamodal">
        <button href="fechar" title="Fechar" class="fechar">X</button>
             <img src="${candidato.caminhoImg}">
                 <h1>${candidato.titulo}</h1>
                    <h4>${candidato.descricao}</h4>
             <p>${candidato.fonte}</p>
    </div>

    `
    document.getElementById("carousel").appendChild(candidatoModal);
    document.getElementById("carousel").appendChild(candidatoEl);
    
    candidatoEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
      candidatoModal.style.display="block"
    });
    fechar.addEventListener("click", () => {
    candidatoModal.style.display="none";
    
    })
    
  });
}
```

Comment: Tentei também, mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que compreendi no seu código, você está criando vários elementos de modal, um para cada item do objeto que você percorre com o foreach, porém todos eles recebem o mesmo ID. Para cada um desses elementos de modal você instancia um evento para estabelecer o "display:block" e instancia outro evento para estabelecer o "display:none".
Seu código tende a não funcionar ao trabalhar com ID repetido, pois ID deve ser único, porém me parece que esse não seja o problema.

Porquê você não cria uma função única responsável por popular o conteúdo do modal e trabalha com um único elemento de modal? Faça algo no javascript como:

```
function abrirModal(titulo, descricao, fonte) {
    document.querySelector('.modal h1').innerText = titulo;
    document.querySelector('.modal h4').innerText = descricao;
    document.querySelector('.modal p').innerText = fonte;

    document.querySelector('.modal').style.display = "block";
}

function fecharModal() {
    document.querySelector('.modal').style.display = "none";
}
```

E no html, faça algo como:

```
<div class="modal" id="iniciamodal">
    <button href="fechar" title="Fechar" class="fechar" onclick="fecharModal()">X</button>
    <h1></h1>
    <h4></h4>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

E então o modal pode ser aberto usando um botão como por exemplo:

```
<button type="button" onclick="abrirModal('Titulo teste', 'Descrição teste do candidato', 'Fonte teste do candidato')">Titulo teste</button>
```

Baseado nisso você usa o seu foreach no javascript para criar uma lista de elementos no html que darão o gatilho para abrir o modal.

Talvez existam erros de sintaxe no código, eu escrevi sem testar. Só para apresentar a ideia mesmo. Espero ter sido útil! Sucesso!

Comment: O problema maior está na hora de fechar a janela do modal com as informações do modal, ela simplesmente não fecha, já tentei fazer de tudo, inclusive adicionei a sua função de fechar, mas também não funcionou, estou perdido já rs

Comment: Entendo que o problema maior está na sua estrutura como um todo, e isso está gerando o bug no fechamento do modal.
A forma que eu sugeri é uma reformulação quase que completa da sua estrutura, e dessa forma funcionará. Uso essa estrutura dessa mesma forma para a lógica de modal nos meus projetos.
O correto é sempre usar um único modal tendo suas informações populadas em tempo real pelo js. Criar um modal para cada item não é a melhor prática. 
Faça um teste! Boa sorte!